# integral of fractional part $\int_0^1\left\{\frac 1x\right\}dx$ convergent?

Tags: integration, summation, fractional-part

$$I=\int_0^1\left\{\frac 1x\right\}dx=\int_1^\infty\frac{\{u\}}{u^2}du=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{\{v+k\}}{(v+k)^2}dv=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^1\frac{v}{(v+k)^2}dv=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ln\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)+\frac k{k+1}-1$$
and I believe the integral should converge but neither parts of this series converge from what ive calculated:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ln\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)=\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k+1}k\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(n+1)\to\infty$$

my reasoning is that if the first substitution is valid:
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\{u\}}{u^2}du\le\int_1^\infty\frac{du}{u^2}=\left[\frac{1}{u}\right]_\infty^1=1$$

---

Thank you for all the comments and answers, using them I have written the sum as:
$$1+lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\ln(n)-\text{H}_n\right]$$
which as has been pointed out is a known value of $1-\gamma$

Comment: Since $\frac{k}{k+1} - 1 = -\frac{1}{k+1}$, the partial sum of it also diverges to $-\infty$ logarithmically. The divergence of the two partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^n \log\frac{k+1}{k}$ and $-\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+1}$ cancels each other.

Comment: @achillehui ahh I see, is there any easy way for me to calculate the value of this summation?

Comment: You can simply use the fact that $0 \le \{1/x\} < 1$ for all $x$.

Comment: There's no doubt that the integral converges because the fractional part is bounded and the function has a countable number of discontinuities

Comment: You can use the result $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \log n\right) = \gamma$ (look at wiki entry of [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, the initial integral must converge. Write it as $$I(x)=\int_{1-x}^1\left\{\frac1t\right\}dt.$$
Since $0\le\left\{\frac1x\right\}<1$ for all $x$, we know that $I(x)$ is monotonically increasing and bounded (on $[0,1]$, and hence must converge).

As achille hui stated, the positive part of your summation diverges -- but so does the negative part! This by no means implies divergence.

In fact, the [Euler Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) is defined to be equal to this difference between the logarithmic function and the harmonic series sum. The integral, when evaluated , should be $1-\gamma.$

Comment: Two problems: first, you can't have x as both the integration variable and a parameter in I(x); second, I(x) is decreasing. All that is needed is that the fractional part is bounded.

Comment: Oh, of course you're right. I've fixed it so that it actually makes sense this time~